# Get the value of the body id and store as a variable in js

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have a need to change something within a page depending on the body tag id.

My code doesn't seem to work, can you help?

```
function changeHeaderTitle(){
    var bodyId = document.getElementsByTagName("body").id;
    alert(bodyId);
}
```

This just echoes "undefined".

Comment: Someone asks this question every day, and yet I can never find a suitable dupe. Please [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns collection of nodes, even if the collection is bound to contain only one element. Try

```
var bodyId = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].id;
// select the first (and only) body:              ^^^
```

or better yet

```
var bodyId = document.body.id;
```

Comment: Note that the direct property access is _much_ faster as well as more readable: http://jsperf.com/unique-by-tag-name

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, try this:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].id
```

because `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.

Comment: Technically, it's a pseudo-array

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id

Note that getElementsByTagName returns an array of obj